# Add New Calendar Type To Sharepoint such as Persian Calndar

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010

can anyone tell me how i can add new calendar type such as Persian Calendar in sharepoint

Answer (score 1):

Persian calendar is not supported in SharePoint OOTB.

I found javascript solution for SharePoint 2003/2007 (don't know if it will work in 2010), please follow the link: http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/84130

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Regional options under site setting to define additional calendar types and other settings

Comment: hi Vladi Gubler and thank for your answer
but i the regional options my favorite calendar not found (Persian calendar) and i want manually add new calendar

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Do you mean like the names of the months and the calendar-specific day count?